# how to auto close brackets and braces in javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you auto close brackets **`[]`** and auto close curly brackets **`{}`**?
I've tried using @Ivan Ganchev's idea:

```
maintextarea.addEventListener('keyup', function (ev) {
let position = this.selectionStart;
   if (ev.keyCode == 222) { // I replaced this with 219 for open bracket and curly bracket
      let value = ev.target.value;
      ev.target.value = [value.slice(0, position), ev.key, value.slice(position)].join('');
      ev.target.selectionEnd = position;
   }
});
```

But it came out like this:
**{{**
or:
**[[**.

Comment: instead of inserting the same character you need to insert the matching character

Comment: This would be editor tool dependent perhaps?

Comment: Please provide the editor tool you are using (as a tag) so we can help you here.

Comment: this is not editor tool dependent.

Comment: Just to clarify what you want to do, if the user types an opening bracket key you want to add the related closing bracket but leave the position where it was, ie so the next character they type goes in between the opening and closing bracket? Is that right?

Comment: Is there a reason you are checking on the key that has been pressed rather than the actual Unicode value of the character? Incidentally, running your code on an iPad with Safari at least I don’t see the extra bracket going in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store characters and their matching closing characters which allows easy addition or customization of character pairs. `Map.get()` fetches the specified element from the map or returns `undefined` which allows for compact checking.

It's also uses an `input` listener instead of `keyup` since you don't need to detect modifier keys and feels a little more responsive (though not supported by IE < 9)

```js
const closeChars = new Map([
  ['{', '}'],
  ['[', ']'],
  ['(', ')']
]);
    
maintextarea=document.getElementById('maintextarea');

maintextarea.addEventListener('input', function (e) {

    const pos = e.target.selectionStart;
    const val = [...e.target.value];
    
    const char = val.slice(pos-1, pos)[0];
    const closeChar = closeChars.get(char);
    
    if (closeChar) {
      val.splice(pos, 0, closeChar);
      e.target.value = val.join('');
      e.target.selectionEnd = pos;
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="maintextarea" name="closebrackets" rows="8" cols="50">
</textarea>
```

Comment: is it possible that when you are in the center, you press backspace both quotes disapear?